# The XAML Principle

Tags: xaml, styles, ui-design

Of so clear separation of UI is unique to XAML?  I mean, you could even customize the entire UI of a 'pre-packaged control/component'...

Any light on other technologies that achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Mozilla's XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL) does something similar.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks! One more Q:  Is XAML first of its kind?

Comment: XUL has been around a lot longer than XAML, I believe